# Vite-Svelte Default Project Won't Build and Dev Server only shows: "Cannot GET /"

Tags: https, build, config, svelte, vite

I have created a default vite-svelte project.

When I run `npm run build` i am getting the error:

```
vite v4.3.9 building for production...
✓ 1 modules transformed.
✓ built in 36ms
[vite:build-import-analysis] Parse error @:5:10

3:   import viteLogo from '/vite.svg'
4:   import Counter from './lib/Counter.svelte'
5: </script>
```

When I run `npm run dev` it is running correctly, but when I navigate to `localhost:5173` (dev server) it shows only `Cannot GET /` on the web page.

What am I doing wrong - I think it might be to do with my `vite.config.ts` (not certain), as I have changed about the file structure - otherwise, the project is identical to the starter template?

`vite.config.ts` for reference:

```
import { UserConfig, defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';

// @ts-ignore
import appSettings from './appsettings.json';
// @ts-ignore
import appSettingsDev from './appsettings.Development.json';

const baseFolder =
    process.env.APPDATA !== undefined && process.env.APPDATA !== ''
        ? `${process.env.APPDATA}/ASP.NET/https`
        : `${process.env.HOME}/.aspnet/https`;

const certificateName = process.env.npm_package_name;

const certFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.pem`);
const keyFilePath = path.join(baseFolder, `${certificateName}.key`);

const cssPattern = /\.css$/;
const imagePattern = /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|avif)$/;

export default defineConfig(async () => {
  if (!fs.existsSync(certFilePath)) {  // Ensure the certificate and key exist
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {  // Wait for the certificate to be generated
      spawn('dotnet', [
        'dev-certs',
        'https',
        '--export-path',
        certFilePath,
        '--format',
        'Pem',
        '--no-password',
      ], {stdio: 'inherit',})
          .on('exit', (code) => {
            resolve();
            if (code) {
              process.exit(code);
            }
          });
    });
  } else if (!fs.existsSync(keyFilePath)) {
    await new Promise<void>((resolve) => {  // Wait for the certificate to be generated
      spawn('dotnet', [
        'dev-certs',
        'https',
        '--export-path',
        certFilePath,
        '--format',
        'Pem',
        '--no-password',
      ], {stdio: 'inherit',})
          .on('exit', (code) => {
            resolve();
            if (code) {
              process.exit(code);
            }
          });
    });
  }

  const config: UserConfig = {
    appType: 'custom',
    root: 'svelte-client',
    base: './',
    publicDir: 'public',
    build: {
      manifest: appSettings.Vite.Manifest,
      emptyOutDir: true,
      outDir: './wwwroot/svelte-client',
      assetsDir: '',
      rollupOptions: {
        input: 'svelte-client/src/main.ts',
        output: {
          entryFileNames: 'js/[name].js',  // Save entry files to the appropriate folder
          chunkFileNames: 'js/[name]-chunk.js',  // Save chunk files to the js folder
          assetFileNames: (info) => {  // Save asset files to the appropriate folder
            if (info.name) {
              if (cssPattern.test(info.name)) {  // If the file is a CSS file, save it to the css folder
                return 'css/[name][extname]';
              }
              if (imagePattern.test(info.name)) {  // If the file is an image file, save it to the images folder
                return 'images/[name][extname]';
              }
              
              return 'assets/[name][extname]';  // If the file is any other type of file, save it to the assets folder
            } else {
              return '[name][extname]';  // If the file name is not specified, save it to the output directory
            }
          },
        }
      },
    },
    server: {
      port: appSettingsDev.Vite.Server.Port,
      strictPort: true,
      https: {
        cert: certFilePath,
        key: keyFilePath
      },
      hmr: {
        clientPort: appSettingsDev.Vite.Server.Port
      }
    },
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: []
    }
  }

  return config;
});
```